# problem creating an EhCache Cache from spring

Tags: java, spring, ehcache

Reading the javadoc for [EhCacheManagerFactoryBean](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/cache/ehcache/EhCacheManagerFactoryBean.html) and [EhCacheFactoryBean](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/cache/ehcache/EhCacheFactoryBean.html) I figured that:

```
<bean id="cacheManager" class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManagerFactoryBean" p:configLocation="classpath:ehcache.xml"/>

<bean id="locationCache" class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheFactoryBean"
      p:cacheManager-ref="cacheManager"
      p:cacheName="locationCache"/>
```

would create a cache that I then can @Autowired in. But I must be missing something because this is what I get:

> Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'locationCache' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: net.sf.ehcache.Cache.(Ljava/lang/String;ILnet/sf/ehcache/store/MemoryStoreEvictionPolicy;  ZLjava/lang/String;ZJJZJLnet/sf/ehcache/event/RegisteredEventListeners;  Lnet/sf/ehcache/bootstrap/BootstrapCacheLoader;II)V

I've tried ehcache 1.7.2, 1.6.2 and 1.5.0.

It works if I specify `<cache name="locationCache" />` in ehcache.xml but I prefer to have my configuration done in applicationsContext.xml

```
<cache name="locationCache" />
```

Comment: which version of spring?

Comment: you need  the 3.1 to use hecache!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The missing constructor belongs to Ehcache 1.3, and it still exists in the newer versions. May be, you have some problem with dependecnies. If you use maven, try `mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose=true` and look for conflicts.

Comment: I found an old ehcache version (1.2.4) on the classpath. Removing that solved the problem. Thanks.